# Font is not loading properly

Tags: fonts, html5-canvas, font-face, fabricjs

I am trying to change font-family of text. using fabric.js. Actually Problem is like, when I select font-family for text is not getting applied. When second time I select same font that time text font-family is change. I don't understand what is wrong.

Below is my font css.

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'GothamBold';
 src: url('../fonts/GothamBold/GothamBold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
 url('../fonts/GothamBold/GothamBold.woff') format('woff'),
 url('../fonts/GothamBold/GothamBold.ttf')  format('truetype'),
 url('../fonts/GothamBold/GothamBold.svg#GothamBold') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}
```

I my fabric script is like below

```
$('#fontFamily').change(function(){
    var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
    if(obj){
        obj.set($(this).attr('id'),$(this).val()); 
    }
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

I tried one solution below but still geting same probelm

```
<FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff)">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

Please tell me about this font problem. Where is the fault in my code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/AppleDev/e4dfn1c4/15/

Comment: I got solution. Firslty load all fonts on page and then apply font on text to change font style.

Comment: Italic font style not working properly for custom font like Monotype Corsiva and scriptoria ssk regular. It's didn't work on chrome, edge or IE browser.
But on mozilla firefox it working fine..
Unable to get actual issue about the font.